# Detecting and Comparing GPIO events in Beaglebone using Python

Tags: python, multithreading, beagleboneblack

I am trying to detect two events in two different GPIOs in the Beaglebone Black, and then decide which one happened first. I am using Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO for the code which is written in Python. It is not working properly, and have no idea why. Here is the code:

```
import sys
import thread
import time
from datetime import datetime
import bitarray
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO

gpio_state = [0, 0]
gpio_time = [0, 0]
ir_recv = ['GPIO0_26', 'GPIO1_12']

def checkEvent(index):
    while True:
        if GPIO.event_detected(ir_recv[index]): 
            if (gpio_state[index] == 0):
                gpio_state[index] = 1
                gpio_time[index] = datetime.now()
                print ir_recv[index]
                time.sleep(5) # time to avoid rebounces

for gpio in ir_recv:
    GPIO.setup(gpio, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(gpio, GPIO.RISING)

try:
    thread.start_new_thread(checkEvent, (0, ) )
    thread.start_new_thread(checkEvent, (1, ) )
except:
    print "Error: unable to start thread"

while True:
    if (gpio_state[0] == 1) and (gpio_state[1] == 1):
        if gpio_time[0] > gpio_time[1]:
            print "1"
        if gpio_time[0] < gpio_time[1]:
            print "2"
        if gpio_time[0] == gpio_time[1]:
            print "???"
        gpio_state[0] = 0
        gpio_state[1] = 0
        gpio_time[0] = 0
        gpio_time[1] = 0
```

I don't get any error. The main problem is that the events are not compared correctly, e.g. although event in GPIO0_26 happens first than the one in GPIO1_12 (i.e. gpio_time[0] is smaller than gpio_time[1]), the output in the last While loop does not print out "2". Also sometimes the code prints out twice the GPIO pin from the threads.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion to find a solution.

Comment: did you get any error . or not geeting expected results if so please provide input and expected output

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар : added the problem i'm having

Comment: Both threads are in a fast busy-wait loop if there's no GPIO data. Consider adding `time.sleep(0.01)`, or find way to block on `GPIO.event_detected()`

Comment: Consider using the kernel's ability to create (timestamped) GPIO input **events**.  See [this article](http://hipstercircuits.com/capture-input-events-via-gpio-on-beaglebone-black/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [PyBBIO](https://github.com/graycatlabs/PyBBIO) for this (granted, I am the author). It has an interrupt API which is based on [epoll](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) (for kernel level interrupt signalling), and would greatly simplify this. Something like this should do the trick (I haven't tested it):

```
from datetime import datetime
from bbio import *

gpio_state = [0, 0]
gpio_time = [0, 0]
ir_recv = ['GPIO0_26', 'GPIO1_12']

def getInterrupt(index):
    gpio_time[index] = datetime.now()
    gpio_state[index] = 1
    print "received interrupt from {} at {}".fomrat(ir_recv[index],
                                                    gpio_time[index]
                                                    )

def setup():
    for i in range(len(ir_recv)):
      pinMode(ir_recv[i], INPUT, pull=-1)
      # The optional pull=-1 enables the internal pull-down resistor

    attachInterrupt(ir_recv[0], lambda: getInterrupt(0), RISING)
    attachInterrupt(ir_recv[1], lambda: getInterrupt(1), RISING)


def loop():
    # You can do other stuff here while you're waiting...
    delay(1000)

run(setup, loop)
```

And you should make sure your PyBBIO is up to date with:

```
# pip install -U PyBBIO
```